# I do not understand how to use the use the integral form of the remainder to find the radius of convergence

Tags: taylor-expansion

The question from the textbook (Multi Calc by Jerry Shurman P. 20):

> $(b)$ Use the integral form of the remainder to show that
> $\ln(1+x)=T(x)$ for $x\in(-1,1]$.

We are asked to show that the taylor series $\ln(1 + x)$ converges for $-1 < x \leq 1$ using the integral form of the remainder which is given by:

\begin{align}
       R(x) &= (-1)^n \int_a^x \frac{f^{(n+1)}(t)}{n!} (x-t)^n dt\\
     \end{align}

I understand the derivation from the integral form of the remainder to the Lagrange form; however, for this problem, it looks like they want us to find the remainder directly from the integral form. So to begin I thought i should find a generilization for the $n+1$ dervatives of $\ln(1 + x)$ which goes as follows:

\begin{align}
       f^{(n+1)}(t) &= (-1)^n(1+t)^{-(n+1)} n!\\
     \end{align}

When we place this into the remainder we get:

\begin{align}
       R(x) &= \int_a^x \frac{(x-t)^n}{(1+t)^{(n+1)}}dt\\
     \end{align}
This is because the negative ones and $n!$ cancel out we should also center the taylor expansion at $0$ (so $a = 0$) in the integral. Furthermore in a taylor series with infinite terms $n$ goes to infinity so to show it converges we need to show that:

\begin{align}
       \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_0^x \frac{(x-t)^n}{(1+t)^{(n+1)}}dt = 0\\
     \end{align}

for $1 \geq x \geq 0$ and then $0 \geq x > -1$. I think because of the integral you need to split it up into to parts. I'm very confused as to how you show this limit goes to zero. I think I have an intuitive understanding for $1 \geq x \geq 0$ as

\begin{align}
       \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(x-t)^n}{(1+t)^{(n+1)}} = 0\\
     \end{align}

because $t \geq 0$ so $(1+t)^{(n+1)}\geq 1$ and so the denominator becomes arbitrarily large as the numerator becomes smaller and smaller. However I do not understand how this could work for $0 \geq x > -1$.

Thank you to everyone that reads the question and tries it out; any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let $|x|<r<1$. Then $\left|\frac{(x-t)^n}{(1+t)^n}\right|\leq r^n$, since $|x-t|\leq r$ and $1\leq |1+t|$. Therefore, the absolute value of the integral is bounded by $r^{n+1}$.

Comment: thank you for your response, I am however still a little confused, and i think your assumption that 1≤|1+| is wrong for the domain x in (-1,0). t would be negative right?

Answer (score 1):

For a different approach using an integral form of a remainder, see equation (2.5) and Section 3 [here](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/analysis/logarctan.pdf).